# Can't select object in list and delete it

Tags: python, del

I've spent an hour or two collectively now trying to figure this problem out but I'm not getting any results. In my program when a defending animal is "killed" it should be deleted from it's registry, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get that to happen. In this instance if I were to initiate a hunter and a buffalo then attack() the buffalo with the hunter the buffalo should be killed and removed from it's classes registry but I can't get python to select that specific buffalo from the registry.

Any help is appreciated.

```
class IterRegistry(type):
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._registry)

class Buffalo(object):
    __metaclass__ = IterRegistry
    _registry = []
    hp = 1
    price = 150
    attacks = 0
    regeneration = 2

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._registry.append(self)
        self.name = name

def createBuffalo():
    for i in range(len(Buffalo._registry),len(Buffalo._registry)+1):
        varname = ("b" + str(i))
        globals()[varname] = Buffalo("b" + str(i))

class Wolf:
    __metaclass__ = IterRegistry
    _registry = []
    hp = 1
    price = 0
    attacks = 2
    regeneration = 1.5

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._registry.append(self)
        self.name = name

def createWolf():
    for i in range(len(Wolf._registry),len(Wolf._registry)+1):
        varname = ("w" + str(i))
        globals()[varname] = Wolf("w" + str(i))

class Hunter:
    __metaclass__ = IterRegistry
    _registry = []
    hp = 2
    price = 0
    attacks = 1
    regeneration = 0
    balance = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._registry.append(self)
        self.name = name

def createHunter():
    for i in range(len(Hunter._registry),len(Hunter._registry)+1):
        varname = ("h" + str(i))
        globals()[varname] = Hunter("h" + str(i))

def attack(attacker, target):
    if attacker.attacks >= 1:
        target.hp -= 1
        if target.hp == 0:
            if type(attacker) == Hunter:
                attacker.balance += 150
            print(target)
            if type(target) == Wolf:
                del Wolf._registry[[n for n in Wolf._registry if n == target]]
            if type(target) == Hunter:
                del Hunter._registry[[n for n in Hunter._registry if n == target]]
            if type(target) == Buffalo:
                del Buffalo._registry[[n for n in Hunter._registry if n == target]]
```

One more note, the reason I have double brackets is because it was incorrect syntax with single brackets but the syntax was fine with doubles.

If you need any more code, ask in a comment below (I have not included all of it but it should be enough).

Comment: Do you just need `Wolf._registry.remove(target)`? (etc)

Comment: this: `globals()[varname] = Wolf("w" + str(i))` is terrible practice. Don't dynamically create variables.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you have a good alternative for this? I've seen lots of people saying dynamically creating variables is a horrible idea but I don't know what else to do in this situation.

Comment: Actually, in this case it is not a bad idea. Just don't use it too much

Comment: Use a *container, like a list or a dict*

Comment: Dictionaries are always perfect, in this case I woud suggest to use the globals()[] function.

Comment: @Sayse Wow, I'm not sure how I didn't think of that in two hours. Works great, thanks a lot.

Comment: That's way too much code. Isolate the problem into a [mcve] which also makes it more likely that you can then solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Don't use a metaclass when you don't need to. Just define a base class that provides the registry attribute to append new instances to. Also, your class attributes should pretty much all be instance attributes. I suggest working through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're trying to solve is caused by trying to use a list as an index to be removed from your list

```
[n for n in Wolf._registry if n == target]
```

All you're trying to get out of this list comprehension is the target, so just use that.

```
Wolf._registry.remove(target)
```